# Error. mysql installer when installing mysql onwndows 10 laptop

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c1nE.png)
when installing mysql there is show a error "mysql installer did not find packages in the current bundle suitable for installation windows".
how can I solve this problem ,I am using windows 10, 64bit with 8GB ram laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and deleting C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL and restarting the installer worked for me.
https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/lw3yy0/issues_installing_mysql_no_packages_found/

Comment: Thanks for your help!